# Javascript function in Angular 10 not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular10

I've created simple code using JavaScript to filter the data from product in Angular 10. But the onkeyup in html does not recognize the search function in typescript. What could be the problem?

StackBlitz URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-scaucq?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `(keyup)` and I couldn't resist to review your code. Using document.getElement and so on is not the angular way of doing things. It can be done much easier. Please have a look at my Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4bgobb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" (keyup)="search(searchTerm)" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"  placeholder="Search for product.." title="Type in a name">


<ul id="myProduct" *ngFor="let product of shownProducts">
    <li><a href="#">{{product.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
constructor(private productService: ProductService) {}
  product: Product[];
  productGroup: ProductGroup[];
  availableProducts: Product[];
  shownProducts: Product[];

  public searchTerm = "";

  search(searchValue: string) {
    this.shownProducts = this.availableProducts.filter((product: Product) => product.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()));
  }

  getProduct() {
    this.productService
      .getProductsSmall()
      .then(products => ((this.availableProducts = products), this.search("")));
  }
```

I've added [[(ngModel)]](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) in your template and replaced your javascript with a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" (keyup)="search()" placeholder="Search for product.." title="Type in a name">
```

Use `(keyup)` instead of `onkeyup`.

Answer (score 1):

According to your example would be better like this
`app.component.html`

```html
<input
  type="text"
  id="myInput"
  (keyup)="search($event.target)"
  placeholder="Search for product.."
  title="Type in a name"
/>

<ul id="myProduct" *ngFor="let product of filteredProducts">
  <li>
    <a href="#">{{ product.name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './product';
import { ProductGroup } from './product-group';
import { ProductService } from './services/product.service';
// import * as var from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {}
  product: Product[];
  productGroup: ProductGroup[];
  availableProducts: Product[];
  filteredProducts: Product[];

  search(e) {
    this.filteredProducts = this.availableProducts.filter(
      (p) => p.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(e.value.toUpperCase()) > -1
    );
  }

  getProduct() {
    this.productService.getProductsSmall().then((products) => {
      this.availableProducts = products;
      this.filteredProducts = products;
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProduct();
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you could not resist either :D. I would suggest to use my approach because it is less complicated.